# Pandoc correctly generates LaTeX but no HTML5 output from an Org-mode file

Tags: org-mode, html

I cannot get an HTML5 output from my Org-mode file, while PDF/LaTeX output is fine.

This is a fragment of my Org-mode file:

```
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \author{Name Surname}
#+HTML_DOCTYPE: html5
```

All I can get is an XHTML file, not an HTML5 one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="" xml:lang="">
```

I tried to specify the format on the command line, but the result did not change:

```
pandoc -s input.org -t html5 -o output.html
```

Comment: This is a question about `pandoc` which has nothing to do with Emacs. You should try the built-in Org mode exporter and see if you get any results (and at least then the question wil be Emacs-related).

Comment: Out of curiosity: what do you get if you use the built-in HTML exporter with the file above in Emacs and doing `C-c C-e h h` (or `h H` or `h o`, depending on what you want to see)? Does that produce what you expect?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the package `ox-pandoc` to your configuration, which will add `pandoc` to `org-export-backends`, allowing to export to html5. Example configuration:

```lisp
(use-package ox-pandoc
  :defer t
  :when (executable-find "pandoc")
  :after ox
  :init
    (add-to-list 'org-export-backends 'pandoc)
    (setq org-pandoc-options
          '((standalone . t)
            (mathjax . t)
            (variable . "revealjs-url=https://revealjs.com"))))
```

Note you may need to install some other utilities, in case pandoc will complain about (it will specify what is needed).

Comment: And no header ```#+HTML_DOCTYPE:```, no need to use it.

Comment: Do you need `pandoc` in order to export to HTML5? Doesn't the built-in HTML exporter support that?

Comment: Yes, you need Pandoc >=2.0 and Pandoc-Citeproc >=0.3. The built-in HTML exporter generates only html 1.

Comment: I'll be the first to admit that I know very little about HTML in general and HTML5 in particular, but `generates only html 1` is not  true, is it? There is `org-html-html5-fancy` and `org-html-html5-elements` options that at least provide translations of special blocks to HTML5 elements and `org-html-doctype` lists nine types, including `html5` and `xhtml5`. Why isn't that enough? What more does HTML5 export through pandoc offer?